# How to iterate using json_normalize()?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

```
   match_files = []
        for x in glob.glob(r'path\**\*.json', recursive=True):
        match_files.append(x)

with open (match_files[0],encoding ='utf8') as fh:
            mat = json.load(fh)
```

This is my data, which is a list:

```
[{'id': 1816, 'name': 'Constantin Gâlcă', 'nickname': None, 'dob': '1972-03-08', 'country': {'id': 187, 'name': 'Romania'}}]
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 230, 'name': 'Diego Pablo Simeone', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 11, 'name': 'Argentina'}}]
[{'id': 238, 'name': 'Enrique Setién Solar', 'nickname': 'Quique Setién', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
[{'id': 238, 'name': 'Enrique Setién Solar', 'nickname': 'Quique Setién', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 25, 'name': 'Santiago Hernán Solari Poggio', 'nickname': None, 'dob': '1976-10-07', 'country': {'id': 11, 'name': 'Argentina'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 229, 'name': 'Eusebio Sacristán Mena', 'nickname': 'Eusebio Sacristán', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 677, 'name': 'Joan Francesc Ferrer Sicilia', 'nickname': 'Rubí', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 221, 'name': 'José Luis Mendilibar Etxebarria', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 187, 'name': 'Abelardo Fernández Antuña', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 234, 'name': 'Pablo Javier Machín Díez', 'nickname': 'Pablo Machín', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 576, 'name': 'Sergio González Soriano', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 211, 'name': 'Marcelino García Toral', 'nickname': None, 'dob': '1965-08-14', 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 182, 'name': 'Javier Calleja Revilla', 'nickname': 'Javi Calleja', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 219, 'name': 'Francisco José López Fernández', 'nickname': 'Paco López', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 767, 'name': 'Gaizka Garitano Aguirre', 'nickname': 'Gaizka Garitano', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 228, 'name': 'José Bordalás Jiménez', 'nickname': 'José Bordalás', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
[{'id': 36, 'name': 'Josep Guardiola i Sala', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
```

How to convert this to a dataframe with each and every element in dictionary as the column name and its value in the corresponding rows.
There are certain elements in here which are lists containing dicts as their items. These do not change to column names when i use

```
df = pd.json_normalize(mat)
```

Those lists with dicts become as seen in the pic below :

[image]

In the above pic,the column **home_team.managers** has a dict as its element. But i need each element in its dict to be a column with corresponding values as rows.

Comment: kindly share data, not pics. Also include ur expected output

Comment: Please share your json

Comment: I've shared the data and explained the way in which i want the output ! Do reply guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this, `test.txt` has the data you posted above:

```
dfs = []
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:

        line = line.replace("'", '"')
        line = line.replace("None", '"None"')
        line = line.replace("nan", '[]')
        data = json.loads(line)
        df = pd.json_normalize(data)
        dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=['index'])
print(df)

      id                             name           nickname         dob  country.id country.name
0   1816                 Constantin Gâlcă               None  1972-03-08         187      Romania
1    793     Luis Enrique Martínez García       Luis Enrique        None         214        Spain
2    230              Diego Pablo Simeone               None        None          11    Argentina
3    238             Enrique Setién Solar      Quique Setién        None         214        Spain
4    793     Luis Enrique Martínez García       Luis Enrique        None         214        Spain
5    793     Luis Enrique Martínez García       Luis Enrique        None         214        Spain
6    793     Luis Enrique Martínez García       Luis Enrique        None         214        Spain
7    793     Luis Enrique Martínez García       Luis Enrique        None         214        Spain
8    238             Enrique Setién Solar      Quique Setién        None         214        Spain
9     25    Santiago Hernán Solari Poggio               None  1976-10-07          11    Argentina
10   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
11   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
12   229           Eusebio Sacristán Mena  Eusebio Sacristán        None         214        Spain
13   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
14   677     Joan Francesc Ferrer Sicilia               Rubí        None         214        Spain
15   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
16   221  José Luis Mendilibar Etxebarria               None        None         214        Spain
17   187        Abelardo Fernández Antuña               None        None         214        Spain
18   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
19   234         Pablo Javier Machín Díez       Pablo Machín        None         214        Spain
20   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
21   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
22   576          Sergio González Soriano               None        None         214        Spain
23   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
24   211           Marcelino García Toral               None  1965-08-14         214        Spain
25   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
26   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
27   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
28   227         Ernesto Valverde Tejedor   Ernesto Valverde        None         214        Spain
29   182           Javier Calleja Revilla       Javi Calleja        None         214        Spain
30   219   Francisco José López Fernández         Paco López        None         214        Spain
31   767          Gaizka Garitano Aguirre    Gaizka Garitano        None         214        Spain
32   228            José Bordalás Jiménez      José Bordalás        None         214        Spain
33    36           Josep Guardiola i Sala               None        None         214        Spain
```

Comment: Read the documentation. You have to install it first `pip install flatten_json`

Comment: I've edited my data and as you can see it's a list with dictionaries and some NaN values.

Comment: Read how to use `flatten_json` properly. You can convert lists and dict to dataframes. If you want to use `json_normalize` you need to flatten each path separately and then merge them together. There's no quick fix solution to nested jsons.

Comment: If there are None type objects, the flatten_json() returns an error. It converts lists and dicts only if there are values.

Comment: What do you want to do with nan?

Comment: Ok you can mark this as the answer and consider upvoting it too.

Comment: Have less than 15 reps man, so it won't be showing it seems ! Sorry